# Plotting a discrete-time signal shows amplitude modulation

Tags: graphics, rendering, signal-processing

I'm trying to render a simple discrete-time signal using a `canvas` element. However, the representation seems to be inaccurate. As you can see in the code snippet the signal *appears* to be amplitude modulated after the frequency reaches a certain threshold. Even though it's well below the Nyquist limit of `<50Hz` (assuming a sampling rate of `100Hz` in this example).
For very low frequencies like `5Hz` it looks perfectly fine.

How would I go about rendering this properly? And does it work for more complex signals (say, the waveform of a song)?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const frequencyElem = document.querySelector('#frequency');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const renderFn = t => {
    const signal = new Array(100);
    const sineOfT = Math.sin(t / 1000 / 8 * Math.PI * 2) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    const frequency = sineOfT * 20 + 3;

    for (let i = 0; i < signal.length; i++) {
      signal[i] = Math.sin(i / signal.length * Math.PI * 2 * frequency);
    }

    frequencyElem.innerText = `${frequency.toFixed(3)}Hz`

    render(ctx, signal);
    requestAnimationFrame(renderFn);
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(renderFn);
});

function render(ctx, signal) {
  const w = ctx.canvas.width;
  const h = ctx.canvas.height;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.beginPath();

  signal.forEach((value, i) => {
    const x = i / (signal.length - 1) * w;
    const y = h - (value + 1) / 2 * h;

    if (i === 0) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
  });

  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #f6f6f6;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<br/>
Frequency: <span id="frequency"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks right to me.  At higher frequencies, when the peak falls between two samples, the  sampled points can be a lot lower than the peak.

If the signal only has frequencies < Nyquist, then the signal *can be reconstructed* from its samples.  That doesn't mean that the samples *look like* the signal.

As long as your signal is oversampled by 2x or more (or so), you can draw it pretty accurately by using cubic interpolation between the sample points.  See, for example, Catmull-Rom interpolation in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline

You can use the `bezierCurveTo` method in HTML Canvas to draw these interpolated curves.  If you need to use lines, then you should find any maximum or minimum points that occur between samples and include those in your path.

I've edited your snippet to use the `bezierCurveTo` method with Catmull-Rom interpolation below:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const frequencyElem = document.querySelector('#frequency');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const renderFn = t => {
    const signal = new Array(100);
    const sineOfT = Math.sin(t / 1000 / 8 * Math.PI * 2) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    const frequency = sineOfT * 20 + 3;

    for (let i = 0; i < signal.length; i++) {
      signal[i] = Math.sin(i / signal.length * Math.PI * 2 * frequency);
    }

    frequencyElem.innerText = `${frequency.toFixed(3)}Hz`

    render(ctx, signal);
    requestAnimationFrame(renderFn);
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(renderFn);
});

function render(ctx, signal) {
  const w = ctx.canvas.width;
  const h = ctx.canvas.height;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.beginPath();

  const dx = w/(signal.length - 1);
  const dy = -(h-2)/2.0;
  const c = 1.0/2.0;

  for (let i=0; i < signal.length-1; ++i) {
    const x0 = i * dx;
    const y0 = h*0.5 + signal[i]*dy;
    const x3 = x0 + dx;
    const y3 = h*0.5 + signal[i+1]*dy;
    let x1,y1,x2,y2;
    if (i>0) {
      x1 = x0 + dx*c;
      y1 = y0 + (signal[i+1] - signal[i-1])*dy*c/2;
    } else {
      x1 = x0;
      y1 = y0;
      ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
    }
    if (i < signal.length-2) {
      x2 = x3 - dx*c;
      y2 = y3 - (signal[i+2] - signal[i])*dy*c/2;
    } else {
      x2 = x3;
      y2 = y3;
    }
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
  }

  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #f6f6f6;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<br/>
Frequency: <span id="frequency"></span>
```

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. So I guess I have to oversample and interpolate in between the original samples, right? If I'm not mistaken linear interpolation would be useless in this case. Are there any proper methods? A quick google search lead me to `Whittaker-Shannon Interpolation`, but maybe you can shed some more light onto that.

Comment: If you want to draw a nice signal, I'd suggest 2x oversampling, followed by any kind of cubic spline interpolation to find any maxima and minima that occur between sample positions.  You can draw straight lines between the points if you include the sample points AND any maxima/minima

Comment: Could you add that to your answer so it's easier for other people to see? I will mark it as accepted then :)

Comment: Actually, I have two more questions. Every `3n+1`th sample is interpolated via cubic spline interpolation and every `3n+2`th sample corresponds to the maximum / minimum? So my final signal has three times as many samples as the original one, right?

Comment: No, you oversample to get 2n samples, and then cubic interpolation gives you a cubic polynomial for all the points between samples. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) Between every pair of samples, you mathematically determine whether or not there is a maximum or minimum point and if so, it's exact coordinates.  Then you you draw lines between the 2n samples *and* any maximum or minimum points.

Comment: or... you could just oversample by a lot instead

Comment: So I'm using cubic hermite spline interpolation to get the values between my original samples now. However, I get a lot of overshooting (Interpolated value is `>1` or `<-1`) and I'm not sure what tangent I should choose to make it work. Using the sign of `p0` as the tangent at `p0` and `0` for the tangent at `p1` is the closest I got so far.

Comment: Easiest choice for choosing the tangents is the Catmull-Rom spline (see the article I linked)

Comment: Would it be okay with you if I send a JSFiddle so you can take a quick look? I'm having a little trouble getting the expected result.

Comment: I fixed up your original post in the answer