# draw sines at higher freq

Tags: plot, signal-processing, trigonometry, resampling

I'm trying to plot some sine waves (code example in plain js [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x1t3p2en/)).

When freq is "low" (`freq` = 10 hz in that case), the plot is quite nice:

[image]

The problem is when I increase the freq (try to set `var freq = 50` for example):

[image]

lots of ripples, it becomes distorted and not so good as plot. If I increment it more, even worse (`var freq = 8030` for example is terrible).
When I see those kind of graph on pro systems, they are displayed just fine.

How would you improve it? FFT, splines, whatever? Which is the right approch?

I don't really need accurancy (i.e. for waveform analysis or whatever), just plot it nicely (as in Desmos https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eodkjlywjh, for example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting a discrete-time signal shows amplitude modulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723584/plotting-a-discrete-time-signal-shows-amplitude-modulation)

Comment: @MattTimmermans not really, because this require to render x2 the signal at least. I mean: if my max signal is 20khz, the width should be 44100. which will calculate "sin" 44k times (lots of resources used...)

Comment: When the frequency is so high that you have more than 1/2 cycle per pixel, you can just draw a big solid rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Like Matt said, the problem here is the same as in [plotting a discrete-time signal shows amplitude modulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723584/plotting-a-discrete-time-signal-shows-amplitude-modulation): "At higher frequencies, when the peak falls between two samples, the sampled points can be a lot lower than the peak." This causes the peaks of the waveform to vary, making a kind of ripple visual effect at the top and bottom of the plot.

Increasing the sampling resolution helps. If you can't increase sampling resolution by much, adjust the sampling resolution to the closest integer multiple of the sine's frequency and set the sampling phase so that it samples the waveform peaks. For instance for a 100 Hz wave `cos(2 π (100*x + 0.3))`, you could sample at 400 Hz at x[n] = n/400 - 0.003. That way there are four samples per period, with x[0], x[4], x[8], ... sampling exactly on the peaks.

Another thought: plotting with a thicker line can help to smooth over some defects. It looks like the desmos example that you linked is using something like a 3-pixel line width.